# PHP Two Arrays - If they are different then insert - Otherwise Update

Tags: php, arrays

I have some data, one array from CSV File, another array contains a value of a field in a post.

With this data, i would like to check if the value of the field is in the CSV then update the field, if not and there is a difference to insert the field into a post.

`$csv_data` array has lots more fields than `$vrm` array. I think I need a function that says, if element is in array then, however I am unsure how to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$vrm = [];
foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $vrm[] = $vehicle->REGISTRATION;
}

$difference = array_diff($csv_data, $vrm);

if(empty($difference)) {
    echo "Need to Update";
} else {
    echo "Need to insert";
}
```

Is anyone able to assist me with this or point me in the right direction please?

** EDIT **

Array `$vrm` is:

```
Array ( [0] => CV56IPG, 
        [1] => RT56KLP, 
        [2] => AB12HNJ)
```

Array `$csv_data` is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                    [REGISTRATION] => CV56IPG 
                    [MAKE] => Volkswagen 
                    [MODEL] => Polo 
                    [DERIVATIVE] => 1.2 Match 5dr 
                    ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                    [REGISTRATION] => AB12HNJ 
                    [MAKE] => Volkswagen 
                    [MODEL] => Polo 
                    [DERIVATIVE] => 1.2 Match 5dr 
                    )
    )
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the 2 array please.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added these to the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your word.

I guess, If you have $vrm unique id, If you use haspMap, you can do this.

```
{
    vrm_id1: vrm_data1,
    vrm_id2: vrm_data2
}
```

if you insert or update new data.

when vrm_id is not exist => insert.

when vrm_id is exist => update.